# retreiving checkbox data along with the textbox data when a check box is checked

Tags: html, node.js

I am M.Boopalan

I am trying to retrieve the textbox data which is disabled when corresponding checkbox is checked.

**Note : That textbox and checkbox are in a particular card div. The cards are more than 5.**

front end : HTML and EJS
Back end : nodejs (express)

Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title text-primary"> 
  <input type="text" value="<%= res[j].d_name %>" name="<%= res[j].d_name %>" disabled>
   </h5>
   <p class="card-text">Type of Variety : <strong> <%= res[j].category %>
   </strong> </p>
   <input type="checkbox" value="<%= res[j].price %>" name="itemPrice">
   <span class="text-danger">INR : Rs.<%= res[j].price %></span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: please add the relavant code that you have tried so far

Comment: Really sorry, I have only the html code alone

Comment: is price a boolean value??

Comment: Price is not a boolean value